# How to take mvc c# server errors +number to line number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, model-view-controller, error-handling

Hi I've coded my MVC c# application and it's all fine, however there does seem to be a few bugs. This being one of my first applications, I'm not surprised.

The application though is internal and so I do get good feedback from the users.

They do give me the screens shots 'Server Error in ........ Application'

This gives me the controller action which does help narrow down the error. 
However how do I turn the +number at end of the line to an actual line number.
I'm aware that this is some sort of byte offset, but getting a rough idea of the line number would be helpful. Is there a plugin or something I can use?

Or is there another way to handle these. I've got a Base controller that all the controllers extend from - I've seen some things that say you can use this to write to a file to give you information about the error. If I made it a generic file (similar to the php error file) then that would help me with any application I make.

Comment: Do you get feedback from the users on what they were doing at the time of the error? Do you utilize `try...catch` patterns?

Comment: Did you set <customErrors mode="Off"/> in web.config?

Comment: @VivekSign - yes - but I could do with more detail.

Comment: @MadMyche could you give me an example, ideally I could do with en example that handled all requests - using a base controller for example

Comment: Can you recreate the users' errors?

Comment: @MadMyche It's a bit tricky I don't think he knew what he did! In the end I looked at the code and attempted to think what 'might' have happened and fixed that. But it would have been nice to have more detail, line number errored on the things he posted, session variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle server errors in Global.asax inside `Application_Error()` method. Create a well designed error page and save it somewhere inside your project. In global asax create a method and put error handling code inside it. See below for example code.

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    if (httpContext.AllErrors != null)
    {
        // you can handle message 
        var message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(httpContext.AllErrors[0]);
        //you can redirect ugly server error page to the one you created
        httpContext.Response.Redirect($"~/Error/Global");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this puts a pretty bandage on the error page, how does it help him fix the error?

Comment: @MadMyche as I explained in the comment inside the above code, httpContext.AllErrors[0] gives the line number within the error details.

Comment: But it should be giving the same information as the YSOD. What the OP needs to learn is how to use that info.

Comment: Ah - so then output those errors to a nice file or email - ready for debugging. Nice thanks - I'll give that a go

Comment: @MadMyche Thanks for your input I took what you said and developed it on my own (see below). I've been a PHP developer for 8 or so years so this has been my first C# year. It's good just different and the way to manage errors is very different. Thanks for your help. Richard

Comment: @RichardHousham Any possibility you called me as MadMyche? :)

Comment: Looks like that may be a possibility,

Answer (score 0):

Just developing on what hhh's answer here.
This is what I've got at the end.

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {
            if (this.Context.AllErrors != null)
            {
                var p = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "Errors.log");

                var message = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                message = message + " " + this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
                message = message + " " + this.Context.Request.Url;
                message = message + Environment.NewLine;

                message = message + "Post";
                message = message + Environment.NewLine;

                string[] keys = this.Context.Request.Form.AllKeys;
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    message = message+keys[i] + ":" + this.Context.Request.Form[keys[i]];
                    message = message + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                message = message + Environment.NewLine;
                // you can handle message 
                message = message+ HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.Context.AllErrors[0]);
                message = message + Environment.NewLine;
                message = message + "----------------------------------";
                message = message + Environment.NewLine;



                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(p, message);


                //you can redirect ugly server error page to the one you created
            }
        }
```

Basically giving you a file with all the key variables in the there.
Feel free to modify as you wish.